# AWS Athena (awswrangler) query optimization

Tags: amazon-web-services, optimization, amazon-athena

I'm wondering what would be the fastest way to query two Amazon Athena tables with with an `INNER JOIN`? I know the technical details in Spark but not in Athena.

Basically, I have two tables A and B where A contains around 42,000,000 rows.

Each of the tables have a column `event` containing a json dictionary expressed as a string. I can access the data using this command:

```
json_format(json_extract(event, '$.data.resource.companyId')) as companyId
```

For documentation and ease of use, I have created a python file with different functions containing each query:

```py
def queryA():
    queryA = """
        
       SELECT
          xx,
          yy
       FROM
          tableA
       WHERE
         different filters

    """

   return queryA


def queryB():
    queryB = """
        
       SELECT
          xx,
          yy
       FROM
          tableB
       WHERE
         different filters

    """

   return queryB
```

What would be the **fastest or more efficient way** to join the two, between using a WITH statement, creating both subqueries and joining them afterwards or creating a single query joining them directly:

**Method 1:**

```py
WITH AAA as (
        {queryA}
),
BBB as (
      {queryB}
)

SELECT
 *
FROM 
 AAA as a
JOIN
 BBB as b
ON
 a.id = b.id
```

**Method 2:**

```
SELECT 
   a.XX
   a.YY
   b.WW
   c.ZZ
FROM
  tableA a
JOIN
 tableB b
ON
 a.id = b.id
WHERE
  different filters
```

I have tried both but for now it is crashing due to a lack of memory.

My question is purely theoretical for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can [Use EXPLAIN and EXPLAIN ANALYZE in Athena - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/athena-explain-statement.html) to learn how the query engine will optimize queries.

As a general rule, when dealing with large tables it is beneficial to limit the number of rows returned *before* performing a Join rather than *after* the join (Method 1), especially where most of the rows are filtered out. However, only EXPLAIN can tell you the actual way the query will be performed.

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much. I actually don't have access to the aws console being restricted from my client security but i'll try through awswrangler$